# What make it so hard for a neural network to learn a classifier that class of x/256 is x?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

1. What I'm original doing is to classify some wave data using neural network. In that problem, I've a vector of about size 200 and number of classes is 256. However, the loss never goes down.
2. So, I think, what about the wave is just the label? `$wave_i(x) = N(i/256.0, (1/10000)^2)$`, will labled `i`, N stand for normal distribution, for example.
3. For very small classes, like 32 or 64, NN works well, and learning rapidly.
4. When I take it to `classes = 256`, however, the learning speed is unbearably slow and even not learning at all.
5. The model I'm using is pretty simple. I think this is enough to even **memorized** the relationship between input and output. (why? you can easily contruct a unit that output 1 when `abs(input - const) < eps`. )

   ```
   model = Sequential([
       Dense(classes, input_dim=200),
       Activation('sigmoid'),
       Dense(classes * 2),
       Activation('sigmoid'),
       Dense(classes),
       Activation('softmax'),
   ])
   ```

   Then, I fed it data with batch size is 256, every different labels occur once.
6. The result is, the loss reached `2.xxxx` and acc reached `0.07` after 2500 epochs, and stopped changing after 3000 epochs. (acc around `0.09` to `0.1`)

I know more variables need more times to learn. However, it's clear that all single output cell should easily cut down their relationship between others (I have very different input set) so.

```
def generator():
    while 1:
        data = [numpy.random.normal(i/255.0,1/10000.0,225).tolist() for i in range(0, classes)]
        labels = to_categorical([i for i in range(0, classes)], classes)
        yield (data,labels)
```

Comment: This doesn't strike me a really a programming question. You might get better answers on Machine Learning.

Comment: Please explain the relationship between input and output more clearly. I don't understand how your formula in (2) relates to the input and output vectors. Also, you define wave_i as a function of x, but then do not use x (I guess it is implied in your notation, but it would help if clearer?). Maybe a numerical example with really few classes and smaller input vector, e.g. 4, would help.

Comment: @Neil Slater I use wave_i(x) as input for NN. It's just `wave_i === i/256 + (some small random value)` And it should be classified as i. x is not used, because input is only related to label and x for index.

Comment: For example, [0.01568..., 0.01567..., 0.01568..., 0.01568..., 0.01569..., ...] maybe a inputs for label 4. And [0.01953125, 0.01953012, ...] for label 5. It's easy to identify it by human,  `0.01953125 * 256 = 5` so it's 5, `0.01568...*256 = 4.01152` so it's 4.

Comment: @NeilSlater updated a code. That's what I fed to the model.

Comment: OK, got it thanks. There are probably things you can do to address your problem, relating to how real data is processed. However, if you really had such a simple relationship to explore/predict in a data science context, you would not use a neural network, as it makes a lot of extra work and most likely would not be the best possible model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have a really simple relationship between input and output, such as the one you are exploring, then this may not play to the strengths of a neural network, which is flexible enough to fit any function but rarely does so perfectly. When you have a simple function, you may find you will spot the imperfections in the fit from a neural network and models other than neural networks will do a better job.

Some things you could potentially do to get a better fit (roughly in order of things I would try):

1. Try a different optimiser. You don't say which optimiser you are using, but the [Keras library comes with a few choices](https://keras.io/optimizers/).
2. Neural networks work better when training and predicting against input features that have been normalised. An effective choice is mean 0, standard deviation 1. In your case, if you pre-process each batch - when training and testing - like this: `data = (data - 0.5)/0.289`, it may help.
3. Increase number of neurons in hidden layers, and/or change the activation function. Your ideal activation function here might even be shaped like a gaussian (so a single neuron could immediately tune to each class), but that isn't something you usually find in a NN library. Consider dropping the middle layer too, and just have e.g. `8*classes` neurons in a single hidden layer before the softmax*.
4. Sample from your input examples in the generator instead of calculating one from each class each time. The generator is potentially too regular - I have seen the classic `xor` example network get stuck in a similar way to your description when fed the same inputs repeatedly.

---

* The simpler network model would look like this:

```
model = Sequential([
  Dense(classes * 8, input_dim=200), 
  Activation('sigmoid'), 
  Dense(classes), 
  Activation('softmax'), 
])
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mention which optimiser I've used because they works basically... the same. Normalized data seems not change anything. And more neurons can improve the accurate rate but much more slowly (notice that I have only one hidden layer..). Use some designed activation function should be useful for this case. But I'm more curious about why NNs doing so bad at memorizing some pattern in given

Comment: sequences (so I use such simple pattern). It not looks like some articles said NNs can be trained to learn (or extract?) some low level patterns like shapes, lines (for 2d, but these should do for 1d I assume, shape of wave?) and by combining them as high level patterns for recognizing and classifying. If they doing so bad at even "recite" [0.2 0.2] is 51, [0.1 0.1] is 25 (and should active them in the output layer), how can they even achieve to combining them? Is 256 classes too large for normal NNs?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong. Normalized didn't help accurate rate but it did improved loss... But I'm still can't understand if they can remember 2d-patterns, why can't they matching some simple value?

Comment: @Yangff: You have *two* hidden layers in your question. Try removing one and increasing number of neurons in first one.

Comment: It seems that I make a mistake here... I shouldn't put a Activation function after input layer... and remove it do improve the accuracy... but slightly. And adding more neurons in the first layer, (like `8*classes` instead of `2*classes`) didn't make a big change also. Overall, the best accuracy I get now still around 10%.

Comment: And two layers of sigmoid, I think is very suitable for the network to store all 1 to 1 relationship, because, at least, using `A=s((input - target + eps) * 1000000`(a very large number so it get close to `1`), `B=s((-input + target + eps)*1000000`, `output = s((A + B - 2 + eps)*1000000)` can achieve what I want... (`A` standing for `input >= target - eps`, `B` is for `input <= target + eps`, output is `A` and `B` happened at the same time so `input` is between `target - eps` and `target + eps`. (maybe called overfit, but it's better then stuck in 10%...)

Comment: Now, one layer can get acc of 10~13% and two layer can sometimes reach 20%~30% but it's unstable and become 1~10% randomly..

Comment: @Yangff: It seems you are not understanding Keras' layer model. You need to remove the Dense layer as well as the activation.  Try `model = Sequential([
    Dense(classes * 8, input_dim=200),
    Activation('sigmoid'),
    Dense(classes),
    Activation('softmax'),
])`

Comment: Yes... This does works! What's the reason for using only one layer? To reduce the numbers of connections?

Comment: @Yangff: It's because your problem is very simple. Multiple layers in neural networks allow them to tackle more complex problems. But then if you give a deep/complex network a simple problem it can be hard to train it to forget about the complexity. Simple problems rarely need more than one hidden layer.